# How can I set a name to a camera photo and save it to disc?

Tags: rubymotion

I am building an iOS app using Rubymotion.
In this app I want to let the user take a picture and cache/save it to the
disc. The important thing is that I will be able to find it later explicitly.

How can I save camera photos to the app?
How can I select a custom name for the image?

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 0):

I would look into two methods within the [ALAssetsLibrary class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:

- assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:
```

The first will allow you save a UIImage to the Saved Photos Album, returning its assetURL if successful.

The second will allow you to look up an ALAsset by its assetURL.

As for custom names, you'll have to store those within your app along with the assetURL of the image.